# SQL QUERY: Want to query how many viewers per movie_type; (where comedy = comedy & dramatic comedy)

Tags: mysql, sql

made up table

[image]

Basically I want to group by the movie_type, but I want comedy & dramatic comedy to just be counted as one category = Comedy.

Comment: Use group by movie_type eg: `SELECT COUNT(viewer_id) as viewers, movie_type FROM table where movie_type IN('comedy', 'dramatic comedy') GROUP BY movie_type`

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). Also, images of code or tables are not optimal for many reasons, see [Why not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please state your expected result in your Question, not just in your title.

Comment: It seems there is confusing as what your desired result should be (as per your comment [ideally I want the answer to show me: movie_type: comedy - 3, horror -4, drama - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631559/sql-query-want-to-query-how-many-viewers-per-movie-type-where-comedy-comedy#comment110759145_62631598)), so please be specific in your Question, so answerers do not have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case` expression then do aggregation in the outer query

```
select
  movie_type,
  count(*) as total_viewer
from
(
  select
    case
      when movie_type = 'dramatic comedy' or movie_type = 'comedy' then 'comedy'
      else movie_type
    end as movie_type,
    viewer_id
  from yourTable
) subq
group by
  movie_type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace dramatic with null and fetch the results. Below is the query,

```
select ltrim(rtrim(replace(movie_type, 'dramatic ', ''))) as movie_type , count(1) from 
table
group by ltrim(rtrim(replace(movie_type, 'dramatic ', '')));
```

Comment: ideally I want the answer to show me: movie_type: comedy - 3, horror -4, drama - 1

Comment: Can you post your required answer as well